# Impala queries are not returning anything error or data nothing at all

Tags: cloudera, impala

I have created Impala [PARQUET TABLE](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cloudera-impala/latest/topics/impala_parquet.html) OF 50GB data.
I am running a query with joins of 5 tables, grouping and sorting of data.

at the end of the query the server did not respond any output data nether any exception is thrown by Impala.

On cloudera manager i can see one node is in bad health few min back.

**Query:**

```
    select 
    d_year, s_city, p_brand1,
    sum(lo_revenue - lo_supplycost) as profit
from 
    lineorder_kylin_parqt_ext, dates_kylin_parqt_ext ,customer_kylin_parqt_ext, supplier_kylin_parqt_ext, part_kylin_parqt_ext
where 
    lo_custkey = c_custkey
    and lo_suppkey = s_suppkey
    and lo_partkey = p_partkey
    and lo_orderdate = d_datekey
    and c_region = 'AMERICA'
    and s_nation = 'UNITED STATES'
    and (d_year = 1997 or d_year = 1998)
    and p_category = 'MFGR#14'
group by 
    d_year, s_city, p_brand1
order by 
    d_year, s_city, p_brand1;
```

Comment: What do you mean there was no response? Are you positive that the query *should* return data, i.e. perhaps the predicates do not select any rows? Also, when you say 'On cloudera manager i can see one node is in bad health' -- what is the bad health it reports?

Comment: that node role get restarted any yes it should return some output and i got the answer that os is killing impala demon on the node as it is eating so much memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer OS was killing impala demon on the node as it was eating memory. I confirmed that from Kernel logs and on Cloudera Manager as well the demon where query was executing found dead.